# jQuery/Javascript border around empty form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Recently I decided to learn Javascript and have been trying to create a script that will put a border around empty elements before the form is submitted. Essentially I want the form to be live validation and notify the user before they click submit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should share some code you've tried.

Comment: The only code I've tried is simple `getElementById` nothing too advanced because I've only been doing js about a month.

Comment: yep @ZiNNED. But just to get you rolling, you would do something like if(form.box1.isEmpty()) form.box1.addClass('empty-form');

Comment: would form.box1.empty() be live? or would I have to submit the form?

Comment: It's just pseudocode. You would probably want to have a javascript watcher on your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are very many plugins if you want to use jQuery as your title suggests:

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2014/05/15-useful-jquery-validation-plugins.html

Just pick whatever you want :-)

---

Or if you want to use plain JS, just search "javascript form validation" on google, you'll find thousands of entries, e.g.
http://www.learn-javascript-tutorial.com/javascript-form-validation.cfm and  http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptform.php

Comment: Thanks for this, but, would you be able to give me any advice on how this works? I want to learn more about js/jquery but am having a hard time based off the code snippets offline.

Comment: Sure if you'd ask a specific question about a certain piece of code!? I can't explain you something, when you don't provide me an example to be explained.

Comment: @mplungjan: It's good enough for a real beginner.

Comment: Would running a `setInterval` to run a function work to check form fields?

Comment: @user3735481: Yes it would but it's better to validate when the user hist the submit-button instead of time-based.

Comment: I want to validate real time. I don't want them to have to submit and then check for errors.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation

Also maybe this:

http://css-tricks.com/improved-current-field-highlighting-in-forms/

Hope these help!

Comment: @user3735481: Yeah then use the event when the user decofuses the text-field to check wether the input is correct

Comment: It seems that I already had the knowledge to do this but I just couldn't put the pieces together. I am going to use an interval with a function and that should do what I need just fine. Are there any things I should be concerned about with this method?

Comment: Yes - annoyed users. Instead use the keyup event handler on the fields as they are focussed

Comment: Yes or better first check after unfocusing the field using the `blur()` event